# Cocos2d-x - how to make wait second animation till one animation completes ?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am making a card game where i want to draw card one by one. Card has to be deal one by one to player and then dealer respectively.
During this procedure now I want to add animation of card which I have already done but it is happening together. Now I want to make one by one animation
i.e. One card gets open then second card like that

I have tried using CCArray0>addobj(CCSequence)...method here is my code but its not working

```
m_AnimateCardArr = CCArray::create(4);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

switch (i){

case 0: player->draw(card)
    cardAnimation(player,card,500,200);
    break;
case 1: player->draw(card)
    cardAnimation(player,card,550,200);
    break;
case 2: dealaer->draw(card)
    cardAnimation(player,card,500,1000);
    break;
case 3 :dealaer->draw(card)
    cardAnimation(player,card,550,1000);
    break;
}

++mCount;
}

    void CardAnimation(Player* player,Card* card, CCPoint startPts,CCPoint endPts){

        // ,, some code
     m_AnimateCardArr->addObject(CCSequence::create(spawn1,spawn2,finishAnimation,NULL));
     if(mCount>=4)
        card->runAction( CCSequence::create(m_AnimateCardArr));
}
```

As soon as mCount becomes 4 I try to run the action but its not working

Comment: you are creating a new CCSequence* from a CCArray* and run it? i am not familiar with 2.0 but I guess you should get the CCSequence* out from the array and run it instead of create new one using an array.

Comment: If you just want delay, I guess CCDelayTime and CCCallFunc may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use scheduler like this:

```
this->schedule(schedule(SEL_SCHEDULE selector), 2.0f);
```

`SEL_SCHEDULE selector` will be the function you need to call

`2.0f` is a timer for how many seconds you want to delay the call of the function